# Setting Up a Private MediaWiki

Tags: passwords, mediawiki, web-hosting, wiki, wamp64

I have a MediaWiki (1.32.0) running locally via WAMP on my Windows PC. I want to make the Wiki privately available online to people with a username/password that then allows people to see the Wiki.

So basically I have two big problems:

- I've never hosted a wiki before, but I have hosted other, less complicated sites (such as my old personal website on HostGator) - but these sites never required a "back end" to serve content
- I've never created a password blocked website. I'm thinking we'll just have one username/password combo, because we'll only allow 5-20 editors max on the Wiki; there will never be more than 1000 visitors simultaneously (and that's very, very generously high)

Any advice on either of these issues would be much, much appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.

Comment: @RobertColumbia understood! Just curious, is there a Stack that would be more appropriate that you know of? Sorry for wasting anyone's time on this!

Comment: EasyPHP Devserver (development) + Webserver (demo / production) can do that. https://www.easyphp.org

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Miraheze](https://meta.miraheze.org/wiki/Miraheze) free wiki hosting will take care of this easily.

Comment: Thanks! Can you block your wiki from being seen by others?

Comment: All except the _Main Page_ https://meta.miraheze.org/wiki/FAQ#Private_wikis